# Implementing a custom cursor in Swift that works when the application isn't focused

Tags: swift, macos

I'm looking for a way to implement a custom cursor or some way to follow the cursor when your application is running but not focused.

Ideally it would actually replace the cursor, but even adding a smaller icon that follows the cursor would be great.

I know it's possible because the screen capture tool does it and I've seen apps like iCursor in the App Store:

[image: cursor effect]

But I don't need the animation (or effects), just either a replacement cursor or a smaller icon off to the side.

Any resources or direction would be most helpful. Thanks!